# 404 Page Not Found in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter and experiencing the following error after creating new model for the purpose of user dashboard in addition to admin dashbaord. It is really great if some one can help me. I checked previous answers in the StackOverflow but none helped me.

I am experiencing following error.

[image]

Code segment relevant to the error is as follows.

Model code

```
<?php

//Details of queries whicha re used to interact with teh database

class Queries extends CI_Model {

//Created a function with the name getRoles  
    public function getRoles() {
        //Fetch the reocrds from the table
        $roles = $this->db->get('tbl_roles');
        if ($roles->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $roles->result();
        }
    }

    //Created a function with the name getColleges
    //Used to list collge names in addcodmin view page 
    public function getColleges() {
        //Fetch the reocrds from the table
        $colleges = $this->db->get('tbl_college');
        if ($colleges->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $colleges->result();
        }
    }

    public function registerAdmin($data) {
        return $this->db->insert('tbl_users', $data);
    }

    //create function to check whther three is a admin or not...if not only
    //      that add admin button will be appered
    public function checkAdminExist() {
        $checkAdmin = $this->db->where(['role_id' => '1'])->get('tbl_users');
        if ($checkAdmin->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $checkAdmin->num_rows();
        }
    }

//Create function to check the entered email and password existance 
    public function adminExist($email, $password) {
        $checkAdmin = $this->db->where(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])->get('tbl_users');
        if ($checkAdmin->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $checkAdmin->row();
        }
    }

    //Created function makeCollege and return value and 
    public function makeCollege($data) {
        //if value is 0 - and 1 - if the data get inserted into the table 
        return $this->db->insert('tbl_college', $data);
    }

    //Created function register coadmin fot coadmin query called and passing data to the admin.php 
    //used insert method of the db class if inserted value 1 and if not value 0  
    public function registerCoadmin($data) {
        return $this->db->insert('tbl_users', $data);
    }

    //qruery to display all the colleges and details in teh dashboard
    public function viewAllColleges() {
        //get data from differendt table and view them in one single table
        $this->db->select(['tbl_users.user_id', 'tbl_users.email', 'tbl_college.college_id',
            'tbl_users.username', 'tbl_users.gender', 'tbl_college.collegename',
            'tbl_college.branch', 'tbl_roles.rolename']);
        $this->db->from('tbl_college');
        $this->db->join('tbl_users', 'tbl_users.college_id = tbl_college.college_id');
        $this->db->join('tbl_roles', 'tbl_roles.role_id = tbl_users.role_id');
        //get the details and return details 
        $users = $this->db->get();
        return $users->result();
    }

    public function insertStudent($data) {
        return $this->db->insert('tbl_student', $data);
    }

    public function getStudents($college_id) {
        //select fields required to diaply from the college and the student table
        $this->db->select(['tbl_student.id', 'tbl_college.collegename', 'tbl_student.studentname',
            'tbl_student.gender', 'tbl_student.email', 'tbl_student.course']);
        //Common fileds in the both the table
        $this->db->from('tbl_student');
        $this->db->join('tbl_college', 'tbl_college.college_id = tbl_student.college_id');
        //Take only stuednts who has college id (Get the details of all the students with the college id of 3)
        $this->db->where(['tbl_student.college_id' => $college_id]);
        $students = $this->db->get();
        return $students->result();
    }

    public function getStudentRecord($id) {
        $this->db->select(['tbl_college.college_id', 'tbl_college.collegename',
            'tbl_student.id', 'tbl_student.email', 'tbl_student.gender', 'tbl_student.studentname',
            'tbl_student.course']);
        $this->db->from('tbl_student');
        $this->db->join('tbl_college', 'tbl_college.college_id = tbl_student.college_id');
        $this->db->where(['tbl_student.id' => $id]);
        $student = $this->db->get();
        return $student->row();
    }

    public function upgradeStudent($data, $id) {
        return $this->db->where('id', $id)
                        ->update('tbl_student', $data);
    }

    public function removeStudent($id) {
        return $this->db->delete('tbl_student', ['id' => $id]);
    }

}

?>
```

Controller code 1

```
   <?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class Users extends MY_Controller {

    public function dashbaord() { 
        $this->load->model('queries');
        //$college_id=$this->session->userdata('college_id';
        $students = $this->queries->getStudents($college_id);
        $this->load->view('users',['students'=>$students]);

    }    
}
```

Controller code 2

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends MY_Controller {

    public function index() {

        //New function to display add admin button 
        //and commented the existing code of $this->load->view('home');
        $this->load->model('queries');
        $checkAdminExist = $this->queries->checkAdminExist();
        $this->load->view('home', ['checkAdminExist' => $checkAdminExist]);
        //
    }

    public function adminRegister() {
        //loading teh queries model 
        $this->load->model('queries');
        //Calling the getRoles function inside the roles
        //$roles holds the data of 2 records availble in the roles table
        $roles = $this->queries->getRoles();
//        print_r($roles);
//        exit();
//        $this->load->view('register');
//Pass this to an register view in type of an array and pass the data to register view
        $this->load->view('register', ['roles' => $roles]);
    }

    public function adminSignup() {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('gender', 'Gender', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('role_id', 'Role', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('confpwd', 'Password Again', 'required');

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="text-danger">', '</div>');

        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $data = $this->input->post();
            $data['password'] = sha1($this->input->post('password'));
            $data['confpwd'] = sha1($this->input->post('confpwd'));
            $this->load->model('queries');
            if ($this->queries->registerAdmin($data)) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Admin Registered Sucessfully');
                return redirect("welcome/adminRegister");
            } else {

                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Failed to Register Admin!');
                return redirect("welcome/adminRegister");
            }
//            echo '<pre>';
//            print_r($data);
//            echo '<pre>';
//            exit();
        } else {
            echo $this->adminRegister();
        }
    }

    //Create new view for login function in teh welcome controllder
    public function login() {
        //restrict the acess of the login page of welcome controller
        if ($this->session->userdata("user_id"))
        //redirecting to the dash board page
            return redirect("admin/dashboard");
        //End
        $this->load->view('login');
    }

    public function Signin() {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="text-danger">', '</div>');

        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $password = sha1($this->input->post('password'));
            $this->load->model('queries');
            $userExist = $this->queries->adminExist($email, $password);
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($userExist);
            echo '<pre>';
//information saved in the session data will be accesed when teh user loged into the system
            //inside if the yser id exists user details will be stored inside the session
            if ($userExist) {
                if ($userExist->user_id == '1') {
                    $sessionData = [
                        'user_id' => $userExist->user_id,
                        'username' => $userExist->username,
                        'email' => $userExist->email,
                        'role_id' => $userExist->role_id,
                    ];
                    //redirect to teh dash board upon giving teh correct user id and password
                    //settin user data to the dashboard
                    $this->session->set_userdata($sessionData);
                    return redirect("admin/dashboard");
                    //if the coadmin login session creatiion whos id is grater than 1
                } else if ($userExist->user_id > '1') {
                    $sessionData = [
                        'user_id' => $userExist->user_id,
                        'username' => $userExist->username,
                        'email' => $userExist->email,
                        //'college_id' => $userExist->college_id,
                        'role_id' => $userExist->role_id,
                    ];
                    //redirect to teh dash board upon giving teh correct user id and password
                    //settin user data to the dashboard
                    $this->session->set_userdata($sessionData);
                    return redirect("users/dashboard");
                }
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Email or password is incorrect');

                return redirect("welcome/login");
            }
        } else {
            $this->login();
        }
    }

    //crerate logout function for the user to logout
    public function logout() {
        //closing teh session inside logout function usinhg the userid
        $this->session->unset_userdata("user_id");
        return redirect("welcome/login");
    }

}
```

View

```
<?php include("inc/header.php"); ?>
<div class="container">
    <h3>COADMIN DASHBOARD</h3>

    <?php
//    echo $username = $this->session->userdata('username'); 
    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    ?>
    <h5>Welcome <?php echo $username; ?></h5>
    <hr>

    <div class="row">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Student Name</th>
            <th scope="col">College Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Email</th>
            <th scope="col">Gender</th>
            <th scope="col">Course</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <!--                if users contain the data-->
                <?php //if (count($students)): ?>
                <!--                Iterate the array to show he records-->
                <?php //foreach ($$students as $student): ?>
                <tr class="table-active">
                    <td><?php //echo $student->id;  ?></td>
                    <td><?php //echo $student->studentname;  ?></td>
                    <td><?php //echo $student->collegename;  ?></td>
                    <td><?php //echo $student->email;  ?></td>
                    <td><?php //echo $student->gender;  ?></td>
                    <td><?php //echo $student->course;  ?></td>   

                </tr>
                <?php //endforeach; ?>
                <?php //else: ?>

                <!--                If count is 0 table will not display any data-->
                <tr>
                    <td>No records found!</td>
                </tr>
                <?php //endif; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
<?php include("inc/footer.php"); ?>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the url of your page you are trying to access and is there any routing for this that you have setup

Comment: I am suspecting that you have not yet implemented an htaccess file. Try to include `index.php` in the url `collegems/index.php/users/dashboard`

Comment: @Presmelito already added htacess and index.php has been hidden from the url.

Comment: Is that the only route that is not working? How did you get there did you submit any form?

Comment: @Presmelito There are 2 user roles and I logged in as Admin and Co Admin. When i logged in as coadmin i get into this page and error..

Comment: Try to change `users/dashboard` to `Users/dashboard`

Comment: @Presmelito changed the users/dashboard to Users/dashboard in welcome.php . But still its not working